# C# i am not able to display picture in picturebox from database retrieven path

Tags: c#, mysql

I am working on an assignment in which i have to show an image from database retrieven directory path. I am using `pictureBox1.Load(path_string)` method. Unfortunately i can't store paths in database like this: `"C:\\Users\\MyName"` mySQL it automatically changes it to `"C:\Users\MyName"` but `picturebox` doesn't identify it like that. Here are my 2 Questions

1. Is there way i can store paths in mySQL database like that `"C:\\Users\\MyName"`
2. Tell me a way to use simple paths like `"C:\Users\MyName"` in `picturebox`

I already tried `pictureBox1.Load(@Path_string)` but it was also in vain.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: _"i can't store paths in database like this: `C:\\Users\\MyName`"_ - you don't need to. What happens when you just pass the database value to `pictureBox1.Load()`?

Comment: It doesn't show me the picture in the text box with the value like C:\Users\MyName but it do show me with the value  like C:\\Users\\MyName @CodeCaster

Comment: But, if you try pictureBox1.Load(@"c:\Users\MyName\image1.jpg") doesn't work?

Comment: @patriot: When your string is retrieved from the database query, the special characters should be escaped and you should be able to use the path directly in your pictureBox1.Load(). Can you try debugging the value retrieved from database and put it here? It would help us recognize the problem.

Comment: @bdn02 i am retrieving path from database into a string named path.No matter i use pictureBox1.Load(path); or pictureBox1.Load(@path); it dont work

Comment: @frostedcoder i appreciate your answer but that's exactly the problem i am facing here when special characters are escaped the path doesn't work in pictureBox1.Load();

Comment: @patriot: what is the value you get when you put the variable on watch.

Comment: yeah i used messagebox to check the value in path string it is C:\Users\Patriot\Desktop\S\firstname.png @frostedcoder

Comment: You can try copying this path including the file name, paste it in cmd and see if it opens the file, if not, then your path maybe incorrect.
Also try checking the file extensions. These things are often caused by very simple issues.

Comment: @frostedcoder In cmd that path do open the picture.can you tell me is there another way to show pictures in picturebox with the path  C:\Users\Patriot\Desktop\S\firstname.png stored in a string

Comment: You can try this: http://www.dotnetperls.com/picturebox

Comment: @frostedcoder Thanks but i already did what dotnetperls told me to..no effect

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the `C:\Users\MyName` path by directly putting in Run? If you can access the file from Run command of windows then picture box should be populated with the desired image. I think path is invalid.

Comment: nop i tried running it from cmd...what i wrote above is just a demo path to explain my problem

Comment: Try to access the path which u retrived from sql.If u r able to open that file mannually the it should be displayed in the picture box.

Comment: Yeah i am able to open the picture manually.But it is not showing in my picturebox at any cost

Comment: You should specify full path of image and After retriving the image path Try with copying the image in folder of ur executable and create absolute path like string absolutePath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath), @"Images\ac.jpg");

pbCoffeeImage.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(absolutePath);